# How to exclude library dependencies with explicit URL from generated pom?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm moving the [Scala Migrations](http://code.google.com/p/scala-migrations/) project from ant/ivy to sbt.  It optionally uses log4jdbc as a library dependency that doesn't exist in [any public Maven repository](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/wiki/FAQ) (from what I can find).

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "log4jdbc" % "log4jdbc" % "1.1" from "http://log4jdbc.googlecode.com/files/log4jdbc4-1.1.jar"
```

I'd like the generated POM to not include log4jdbc, since it's not in any repository.  Is this a correct assumption that the POM will be better without listing log4jdbc?  Also, will not listing it work better for Scala Migrations users using sbt?

I wrote the following setting to remove the log4jdbc dependency from the POM.  Is there a better, easier way?  Could a setting be added to sbt to do this automatically?

```
// Do not include log4jdbc as a dependency.
pomPostProcess := { (node: scala.xml.Node) =>
  val rewriteRule =
    new scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule {
      override def transform(n: scala.xml.Node): scala.xml.NodeSeq = {
        val name = n.nameToString(new StringBuilder).toString
        if (name == "dependency") {
          if ((n \ "groupId").text == "log4jdbc")
            scala.xml.NodeSeq.Empty
          else
            n
        }
        else {
          n
        }
      }
    }
  val transformer = new scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer(rewriteRule)
  transformer.transform(node)(0)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you mention a POM, I assume you want to support Maven users or you want to publish to a Maven repository.  If that isn't true, you don't need to publish to a POM and you can just work with Ivy metadata like in the Ant/Ivy setup.

Since you know Ivy, the `from(URL)` method is essentially implemented by declaring a custom artifact with its `from` property set to the URL.  Independent of Maven/POMs, Ivy doesn't include custom artifacts in the delivered Ivy file.  (At least, I believe this is standard Ivy behavior and not something sbt configures Ivy to do.)

There isn't a way to provide the URL for a dependency in a pom.xml either, though.  How you handle this might depend on what you expect clients to do, but one fairly general solution is to declare the dependency as optional:

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "log4jdbc" % "log4jdbc" % "1.1" % "compile,optional" from
    "http://log4jdbc.googlecode.com/files/log4jdbc4-1.1.jar"
```

Clients would need to explicitly declare the dependency in order to use it.
Because it isn't a repository, sbt users would still need to duplicate the `from "..."` declaration.  Maven users can only use dependencies in a repository, although they can install it in their local repository manually fairly easily.

Comment: I've updated Scala Migrations to make log4jdbc optional, it'll use it if Class.forName() finds it at run time, otherwise it'll use a normal Connection and do no additional logging.  Right now, when one publishes to repo2.maven.org, isn't the POM the only thing you get to publish for metadata, so its needed even for sbt and ivy users?  Is it OK to publish a POM with made up groupId and artifactId, even if it is marked optional?

Comment: Yes, you need a POM for Maven Central.  I don't know whether it is "approved" to make up the ids.  Maven Central generally requires all dependencies to be on Maven Central, but I'd think this optional dependency would be ok as long as Maven doesn't try to resolve that dependency.