# How to remove projectDependencies from pom?

Tags: sbt

It's similar to: [How to exclude library dependencies with explicit URL from generated pom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345239/sbt-pom-not-including-library-dependencies-with-explicit-url)

I want to remove a project dependency from the target pom because I merge it using fat jars.

I tried `projectDependencies in makePom := Nil`, but it looks like the task `makePom` gets its dependencies from `root/*:ivyModule`:

```
makePom -> ivyModule -> moduleSettings -> allDependencies -> projectDependencies
```

Comment: my workaround for now is: ```... dependsOn (someProject % "optional")```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/l8xASiqKQdc

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `process` field on `MakePomConfiguration` class and supply a function removing the `dependencies` element from the generated `pom.xml`.

#### build.sbt

```scala
import xml.{NodeSeq, Node => XNode, Elem}
import xml.transform.{RuleTransformer, RewriteRule}

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3"

def dependenciesFilter(n: XNode) = new RuleTransformer(new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: XNode): NodeSeq = n match {
    case e: Elem if e.label == "dependencies" => NodeSeq.Empty
    case other => other
  }
}).transform(n).head

makePomConfiguration := makePomConfiguration.value.copy(process = dependenciesFilter)
```

Comment: well just removing the project referenced